# Continuous form with dependent combo boxes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form that has a dependent combo box on it. I have the dependent working individually for each row/record BUT the dependent combo box is blank unless it has focus then it shows the saved data so what I did was placed a text box over the data portion of the combo box and set its control source to the same field as the dependent combo box and required and it worked great BUT unlike a combo box which would show the name it shows the saved data which is a ID number so I guess my question is how can I show the name and not the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give any more description as to what you mean by a "dependent" combo box? Depends on what? Are you switching out the row source for the combo using VBA as the user moves between records?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to clarify, but if the combobox is *bound* to a field of the form, and its `RowSource` displays two columns - say an ID and Name - then giving the first column a width of 0 will persuade it to display the Name, rather than the ID.

You will also need the `Column Count` to be 2 (or more) and the `Bound Column` to be 1 (the ID). Then set the `Column Widths` to **0cm;2cm** (add more values if more than 2 columns).

**Added**
Remove this criteria from your cobmobox's Row Source:

```
[Forms]![frm_DelayMachineOutputSubform]![cboCategory]
```

It is not needed. The ActivityID (and the CategoryID) are obtained for each row in the form.

Remove these lines from the Current event as well:

```
Me.cboActivity.Requery
Me.txtActivity.Requery
```

again, they are not needed (and cause the flicker). Better yet, just delete this event-code.

Comment: Andy, here is whats going on. I got it to work but only by using dlookup for the txtActivity. If you look at my example and move the txtActivity thats on top of the cboActivity you will see that the combobox doesnt show the results unless the record has focus and the column(1) wont work. Here on my skyDrive is the example: [link]http://sdrv.ms/17rbAXg

Comment: Andy, I tried your suggestions and yet the flicker is still there? Every time I change the activity the afterupdae event requerys and causes that row only to flicker. Ideas?

Comment: Delete the AfterUpdate event for the Activity. I'm not sure why you need the AfterUpdate event on the Category either.

Comment: I was assuming you would get rid of the textbox once the comboboxes are working.